# Te put background-image right way

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I am working a section review in HTML and CSS what I want to include background image which is like strips to contain all section. What I have done until now I am to share with you is like image below:

[image]

After this I want that background image which is like strips  to put on the top and div with class .text-review to be over it might we should to set another property for image.
The end of results should to look such as image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

background-image: url('my_image.jpg');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could've also done that in the time you spent writing that reply